# What prevents the 'instance-groups' annotation from being set when creating a multi-cluster ingress on Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to create a multi-cluster ingress on Google Kubernetes Engine using [kubemci](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-multicluster-ingress), however when running the following command the program waits indefinitely for the ingress service to get the `ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/instance-groups` annotation (as illustrated in the output below).

What is preventing this annotation from being set?

**Input**

```
./kubemci create app-mci \
    --ingress=ingress.yaml \
    --gcp-project=app-prod \
    --kubeconfig=mcikubeconfig
```

**Output**

```
% ./kubemci create app-mci --ingress=ingress.yaml --gcp-project=app-prod --kubeconfig=clusters.yaml        
Created Ingress in cluster: gke_app-prod_europe-west4-a_app-europe-west4
Created Ingress in cluster: gke_app-prod_us-east4-a_app-us-east4
Ensuring health checks
Pod app-deployment-c99578769-xdmql matching service selectors app=app (targetport ): lacks a matching HTTP probe for use in health checks.
Pod app-deployment-c99578769-xgq2m matching service selectors app=app (targetport ): lacks a matching HTTP probe for use in health checks.
Pod app-deployment-c99578769-qms7r matching service selectors app=app (targetport ): lacks a matching HTTP probe for use in health checks.
Pod app-deployment-c99578769-tsrsw matching service selectors app=app (targetport ): lacks a matching HTTP probe for use in health checks.
Path for healthcheck is /
Ensuring health check for port: {SvcName:default/app-service SvcPort:{Type:0 IntVal:80 StrVal:} NodePort:30061 Protocol:HTTP SvcTargetPort: NEGEnabled:false}
Health check mci1-hc-30061--app-mci exists already. Checking if it matches our desired health check
Desired health check exists already
Determining instance groups for cluster gke_app-prod_europe-west4-a_app-europe-west4
Waiting for ingress ( default : app-ingress ) to get ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/instance-groups annotation.....
Waiting for ingress ( default : app-ingress ) to get ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/instance-groups annotation.....
Waiting for ingress ( default : app-ingress ) to get ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/instance-groups annotation.....
⋮
```

As you can see my configuration is identical (aside from resource names) to that in the [multi-cluster ingress guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress):

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: gcr.io/app-prod/app:tag
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app
  name: app-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
      name: http
      nodePort: 30061
  selector:
    app: app
  type: NodePort
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: app-ip
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce-multi-cluster
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: app-service
    servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Enable HTTP load balancing

Enable the HTTP load balancing add-on to allow the [load balancer controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce) to set the `ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/instance-groups` annotation.

### Console

1. Edit a cluster.
2. Expand *add-ons*.
3. Enable HTTP load balancing:

[image]

### Command line

```
% gcloud container clusters update [CLUSTER_NAME] --update-addons HttpLoadBalancing=ENABLED

Updating ***...done.                                                                                                                                                              
Updated [https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/***/zones/us-east4-a/clusters/***].
To inspect the contents of your cluster, go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/workload_/gcloud/us-east4-a/***?project=***
```

View the cluster configuration:

```
% gcloud container clusters describe [CLUSTER_NAME]

# ENABLED
addonsConfig:
  httpLoadBalancing: {}

# DISABLED
addonsConfig:
  httpLoadBalancing:
    disabled: true
```

## Configure Services

Ensure that the backend Services used in the multi-cluster ingress are configured correctly.

Services must:

> - Have the same name in all of the clusters.
> - Be in the same namespace in all of the clusters.
> - Be of type NodePort.
> - Use the same port number for all of the clusters.
>
>   — [Setting up a multi-cluster Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress#prepare_your_clusters), Google

#### Credit

- Nikhil Jindal for his insight.
- Ivan for raising [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-multicluster-ingress/issues/204).